@aws-amplify/backend: Module not found: Can't resolve 'path'
In my next.js application, that I am trying to deploy to AWS amplify, I am using @aws-amplify/backend in order to access secrets using as described here. However I always get an error as shown below.
 ⨯ ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/appsync-modelgen-plugin/lib/preset.js:5:1
Module not found: Can't resolve 'path'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/appsync-modelgen-plugin/lib/index.js
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/graphql-generator/lib/models.js
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/graphql-generator/lib/index.js
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/model-generator/lib/graphql_document_generator.js
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/model-generator/lib/create_graphql_document_generator.js
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/model-generator/lib/index.js
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/client-config/lib/model_introspection_schema_adapter.js
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/client-config/lib/generate_client_config.js
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/client-config/lib/index.js
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/backend/lib/backend_factory.js
./node_modules/@aws-amplify/backend/lib/index.js

